# Calculating last 7 days for each day in range

Tags: sql, sql-server

My table (`products`) is as follow:

```
id, productId, price, saleDate
```

I want to build a query that for specific `productId` and specific data range will return the average of the price for the last 7 days for each day in the range.

The following query will give me all the data for specific productId between 1/1/16 and 02/01/16

```
SELECT * FROM products WHERE productId='PS54434' AND saleDate BETWEEN '2016-01-01' AND '2016-02-01'
```

BUT I want that for each day 01/01/16 until 02/01/16 I will receive the last 7 days
so for data 01/01/16 I will receive the average of prices from the 12/26/16-01/01/16

Comment: What version of SQL Server?

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is using a loop. You declare a start date and go back 7 days from that date and get the average price for that date range. Then add 1 day and repeat the process. If you need all the results as a table, create a temp table and store the result from each iteration.

```
declare @startdate date = '2016-01-01';
create table #tmpavgprice (price numeric(10,2));

while @startdate <= '2016-02-01'
begin 
SELECT avg(price) 
INTO #tmpavgprice
FROM products 
WHERE productId='PS54434' 
AND saleDate BETWEEN dateadd(dd,-7,@startdate) AND @startdate;

set @startdate = select dateadd(dd,1,@startdate);

end;

select * from #tmpavgprice; --to get the final result
```

Comment: Don't forget cursors.