# prestosql get average from last 7 days for each day

Tags: sql, presto

The question I have is very similar to the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37552090/calculating-last-7-days-for-each-day-in-range), but I am using Presto SQL (on aws athena) and couldn't find information on loops in presto.

To reiterate the issue, I want the query that:

Given table that contains: `Day`, `Number of Items for this Day`

I want: `Day`, `Average Items for Last 7 Days before "Day"`
So if I have a table that has data from Dec 25th to Jan 25th, my output table should have data from Jan 1st to Jan 25th. And for each day from Jan 1-25th, it will be the average number of items from last 7 days.

Is it possible to do this with presto?

Comment: what is the type of the field 'Day'?

Comment: @Rick the type would be String in the format 'yyyy-mm-dd'

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can try this one

1. `calendar` Common Table Expression (CTE) is used to generate dates between two dates range.

```
with calendar as (                              
select date_generated                               
from (                              
values (sequence(date'2021-12-25', date'2022-01-25', interval '1' day))                             
) as t1(date_array)                             
cross join unnest(date_array) as t2(date_generated)),
```

2. `temp` CTE is basically used to make a `date group` which contains last 7 days for each date group.

```
temp as (select c1.date_generated as date_groups    
, format_datetime(c2.date_generated, 'yyyy-MM-dd') as dates
from calendar c1, calendar c2                               
where c2.date_generated between c1.date_generated - interval '6' day and c1.date_generated                              
and c1.date_generated >= date'2021-12-25' + interval '6' day)
```

Output for this part:

| date_groups | dates |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-01-01 | 2021-12-26 |
| 2022-01-01 | 2021-12-27 |
| 2022-01-01 | 2021-12-28 |
| 2022-01-01 | 2021-12-29 |
| 2022-01-01 | 2021-12-30 |
| 2022-01-01 | 2021-12-31 |
| 2022-01-01 | 2022-01-01 |

3. last part is joining day column from your table with each date and then group it by the `date group`

```
select temp.date_groups as day
, avg(your_table.num_of_items) avg_last_7_days
from your_table
join temp on your_table.day = temp.dates
group by 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You want a running average (`AVG OVER`)

```
select
  day, amount,
  avg(amount) over (order by day rows between 6 preceding and current row) as avg_amount
from mytable
order by day
offset 6;
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried many different variations of getting the "running average" (which I now know is what I was looking for thanks to Thorsten's answer), but couldn't get the output I wanted exactly with my other columns (that weren't included in my original question) in the table, but this ended up working:

```
SELECT day, <other columns>, avg(amount) OVER (
PARTITION BY <other columns>
ORDER BY date(day) ASC
ROWS 6 PRECEDING) as avg_7_days_amount FROM table ORDER BY date(day) ASC
```